# How do you write the set where $2$ numbers are chosen

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, notation

A = the event that the sum of outcomes of $2$ dice being thrown

So do I say

$A = \{14;41;23;32\}$

That looks like I'm saying $41$ (the number) not $4$ from one die and $1$ from the other which happen to add up to $5$.

Is it right or should I write it like this:

$A = \{1,4 ; 4,1 ; 2,3 ; 3,2\}$

Please tell me if neither is right and you know the right way

I'm confused because I know with head and tails you could say

$S = \{HH;HT;TH;TT\}$

but with numbers it seems a bit ambiguous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use ordered pairs? $$(\text {first number thrown}, \text{second number thrown})$$I'm assuming that A is the event that the sum of two numbers thrown on two dice total $5$.

$$A = \{(1, 4), (4, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)\}$$

Comment: Yes. I think this is best. My friend said the lecturer did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Really your set of events is just a set of labels, and labels are not formal mathematical objects. Therefore, as long as the meaning is clear, any definition should do the trick.

Comment: I agree but it's always good to use accepted notation. I think the ordered pairs are best

Comment: I agree, ordered pairs are standard. Nonetheless, for more complicated events a set of clear labels is much simpler than a complete formalization.